# I want to retrieve value from database according to the dynamic textbox autocomplete selected item in java (jsp and servlets)

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

Here is my code below for generating dynamic textboxes(Item, quantity and price) and autocomplete for each items search.
When i select the item from the autocomplete textbox it must display the price of the selected item to the price textbox.[This is my table menu_Item containing ID, menu_item and price. The price value should be displayed in the price textbox according to the dynamic autocomplete textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GbyB.jpg). Can you please help me out for the solution.

```
var addId = 0;
var temp =$("table tbody");
//Adding textboxes dynamically
$(function(){
$('tbody').sortable();
     $(".add").on('click', function(){
        addId++;
         addcontrols=$('<tr></tr><tr><td><input type="text" id="searchitem" class="serch" name="search[] value=""/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="quantity"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="price"></td>
<td><input type="button" class="remove" value="-">
</td></tr><tr></tr>');
         $("table tbody").append(addcontrols);
//autocomplete for search item 
         $("input[name^='search']").keypress(function () {
             $.ajax({
                  url:"Auto",
                  type:"post",
                  data:'',
                  success:function(data){
                      $( "input[name^='search']").autocomplete({            
                          source: data    
                        });
                  },error:  function(data, status, er){
                        console.log(data+"_"+status+"_"+er);
                    },
            });     

    });
 });
    //To remove the dynamic created textboxes of particular row
     $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
         $(this).closest('tr').remove();
     return false;
     }); 
});
```

**Autocomplete.java(Servlet)**

```
public class AutoComplete extends HttpServlet
{
   /* public AutoComplete() {
        super();

    }*/
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();
        try{

        Connection con = DB.getCon();
         Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
         String sql="select item_name from menu_item";
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
         while(rs.next()){
             al.add(rs.getString("item_name"));
         }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         JSONArray json=new JSONArray(al);
         response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.getWriter().print(json);
}
}
```

***Billing.jsp***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="js/EnableDisable.js"></script>
<script src="js/search.js"></script>
<form id="myform"></form>
<div class="text-container">
Table No.:
<input type="text" name="table_no" /><br><br>
<table id="items" border="1" > 
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Items&emsp;&emsp;</th>
<th> Quantity&emsp;</th>
<th> Price&emsp;</th>
<th><button id="ad" class="add">+</button>
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input id="searchitem" class="serch" name="serch[]" value=""/>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</td>
<td><input type="text" id="itmm"  />&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</td>
<td> <input type="text" id="txtqnty"/>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</td>
<td><button id="rmv" class="remove">-</button></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="calculate">
</td>
<td><input type="text" name="total"></td>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the problem? Don't write 'doesn't work'. Instead use F12 console to inspect your javascript and see what's going on

Comment: Generating text-box is working fine.